# Vim will not stop creating backup files (Windows 8)

Tags: backup, windows-8.1, gvim, vimrc

I'm using Gvim on Windows 8.1 and even after setting `nobackup` and `nowritebackup` in _vimrc, Vim insists on creating those pesky backup files (the .ext~ ones).

I'd like to disable this behavior completely (i.e I want them gone, not just moved to another directory with the `backupdir` option. I understand that at some point they may come in handy, but I'd prefer a clean directory :p)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: Oddly enough, the `noswapfile` option worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type the following to find out where the options are being set:

```
:verbose backup?
:verbose writebackup?
```

I had this problem and found that for some reason my .vimrc was sourcing the example vimrc which overwrote my settings.